# Custom theme build - can't add menu functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Trying to follow a tutorial, setting up a Wordpress theme from scratch and can't get the menu option to show.

**functions.php**

```
<?php
function appdevwp_theme_styles() {
    //featured theme support
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    //Menu
    register_nav_menus( array( 
        'primary' => __('Primary menu'), 
        'secondary' => __('Secondary menu') 
      ) );
}
?>
```

If any one can see where I'm going wrong, please share, because every site I've been on suggests that the above example is correct, yet the option still doesn't become available.

Answer (score 1):

You run `add_theme_support` and `register_nav_menus` functions inside `appdevwp_theme_styles` however you do not call `appdevwp_theme_styles` function.
So you have 2 ways:

1. Run your function after initializing. Just add `appdevwp_theme_styles();` line at the end.
2. Run `add_theme_support` and `register_nav_menus` outside of your new function. Just remove this wrapper `function appdevwp_theme_styles() {....}`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alex,

Seems the original post version seems to run ok watching the tutorial, but your way actually works...

```
<?php

    //featured theme support
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    //Menu
    register_nav_menus( array( 
        'primary'  => __('Primary menu'), 
        'secondary'  => __('Secondary menu') 
      ) );

?>
```